# How to write a grammar for hex ints in BNFC?

Tags: bnfc

Here's a tiny grammar for hexadecimal integers.

```
Numbers . Numbers ::= [HexInt];
separator HexInt " " ;

token HexDigit ["0123456789abcdefABCDEF"] ;
rules HexInt ::= "0x" [HexDigit] ;
separator HexDigit "" ;
```

It fails to parse "0xff", however, because the lexer treats "ff" as a single token.  How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to fix it. There seems to be a bug in BNFC that is including the built-in rule for `Ident` even though your grammar doesn't make use of it, and it takes precedence over `HexDigit` in your example (longest match wins).

However you can write a token rule for hexadecimals:

```
token HexInt ({"0x"} ["0123456789abcdefABCDEF"] +) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

In BNFC, the following declaration says that `HexDigits` are to be separated by whitespace (not by *nothing*, as it may seem):

```
separator HexDigit "" ;
```